# Create new M2 breakpoint with .media-width mixin?

Tags: magento2, less

I want to change the breakpoint of some some styles inside a native M2 module (specifically `Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less`).

[Here is a link to the bp in question](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less#L622).

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
```

**I need to change this from `@screen__m` to a custom breakpoint (`800px`).**

*Now, you can't just change that and pass in a new value willy nilly.*

According to the [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd-breakpoints.html), you have to create a new `mixin rule` for a custom mixin.

---

As best I can see, this mixin `.media-width` acts as a giant `switch` statement. And if you haven't defined a `case` for a breakpoint value that is passed, it simply ignores that call.

---

1. So I create a new `variable` in my `variable.less` for my new value:

`@bp-xm: 800px;`

2. I add a new `mixin rule` into `_responsive.less` (I have already ported [this file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/web/css/source/lib/_responsive.less) into my theme already). I add it to the "mobile" section, as I want this to apply on all device types, and `styles-m.css` is always loaded.

`& when (@media-target = 'mobile'), (@media-target = 'all') {
        ...
        @media all and (max-width: @bp-xm) {
            .media-width('max', @bp-xm);
        }

        @media all and (min-width: (@bp-xm + 1)) {
            .media-width('min', (@bp-xm  + 1));
        }
    }`

3. I `call` my new rule by changing the line in the `_module.less` to this:

`.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @bp-xm) {`

---

According to the devdocs, this is all that needs doing to create a new value that is passable into the `.media-width`. But when I run this, the section of code I wrap this `.media-width` code in doesn't output at all. **In the final, rendered, CSS file, this chunk of code simply doesn't exist.**

I must have missed something.

How do you properly create a new breakpoint for use inside the `.media-width` mixin?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out.

**So, I was correct in assuming that the `.media-width` mixin behaves like a `switch` statement.**

The mixin appears to do a `truthy` check for the parameters that are passed (`@extremum` and `@break`), and checks to see if you have a `rule` that matches those values.

Ex:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @bp-xm) {
```

It looks at the above statement and sees if it has a `case` to handle where
`@extremum = 'min'` and `@break = @bp-xm`.

---

My issue ended up being that I had successfully created 2 new mixin `rules`, but there were to handle the following cases:

```
@extremum = 'max'; @break = @bp-xm;
@extremum = 'min'; @break = (@bp-xm + 1);
```

But I never called it with those paramaters. I called it with these:

```
@extremum = 'min'; @break = @bp-xm; // I never made a rule to handle this case
```

To fix my issue, I simply needed to change my call from being `(@break = @bp-xm)` to `(@break = (@bp-xm + 1))`

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = (@bp-xm + 1)) {
```