# Mobile menu breakpoint in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, menu

How do you change the breakpoint at which mobile menu appears in Magento 2?

Comment: this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd-breakpoints.html) may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to replace style in **web\css\source** `_navigation.less` in your custom theme.

For **Desktop**

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
```

to (your custom width)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
```

---

And for **Mobile**

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
```

to (your custom width)

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
```

Remember one thing you have to add **max-width** is `-1` from **min-width**.

Comment: This doesn't work. Tested in Magento 2.2.7.

Comment: This is the correct way: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131476/create-new-m2-breakpoint-with-media-width-mixin

Comment: @cycpher909 yes It's not working for me to. I have show toggle menu in 768 to 1024 to. Can you please help me?

Comment: Any help to solve mobile menu error https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328503/custom-theme-after-move-catalog-topnav-to-header-panel-mobile-view-category-disp

Comment: For my clarity, just copy from vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\source\ _navigation.less and put into my custom theme  app\design\frontend\zero_theme\theme\web\css\source\ _navigation.less right?

Comment: Yes, if your parent theme is blank. Otherwise, take this file from the parent theme.

Comment: After updated mobile view, hamburger menu visible in tablet view but when i click hamburger menu categories and account links not visible https://snipboard.io/DWFXhG.jpg when i click hamburger menu https://snipboard.io/CTs1jW.jpg any help thanks

Answer (score 7):

The JS for the menu that has that functionality can be found in

> lib/web/mage/menu.js

First create the folder structure in your theme ex:

> [Namespace]/[theme_name]/web/mage/

And copy menu.js from `lib/web/mage/menu.js` to `[Namespace]/[theme_name]/web/mage/menu.js`

And change

```
 mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 768px)'
```

to

```
mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 1025px)'
```

And copy css from mobile and write specific brakpoint

Comment: not working, Can you please share proper way

Comment: Copy menu.js file from lib/web/mage/menu.js and paste into your frontend theme like Frontend/Theme/Themename/web/mage/menu.js

Comment: Then search text "mediaBreakntpoi" into your theme menu.js file.

Comment: you can find something like mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 768px)'

Comment: just replace whatever width you want to set for mobile view breakpoint like: mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 1025px)'

Comment: THANKS IT WORKS

Comment: Not working for me !

Comment: where did you changed?

Comment: try deploy content and remove cache

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to overide the value in your theme of the `@screen__m` LESS variable.  But this will not only change the mobile breakpoint for the navigation, it will change the mobile breakpoint everywhere.

Add to your theme's **_extend.less**

```
@screen__m: 960px;
```

Also, for best performace results you should add the following file to your theme

**Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 960px)"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

For more info see:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_css.html

Comment: This feels like the best, easiest and correct way to do this.