# Change mobile menu breakpoint

Tags: magento2

I would like to change the mobile breakpoint from 767px to 900px but I can't seem to get it to work eventhough I have been following what is instructed in [This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143519/mobile-menu-breakpoint-in-magento-2). Would really appreciate to have a proper instruction or code sample if possible on how to achieve this. I tried modifying lib/web/mage/menu.js but still no luck