# Magento2 How to change the mobile menu breakpoints from 767px to 1024px?

Tags: mobile-menu

I would like to display mobile menu for tablet or iPad, for testing I have changed the media breakpoints from 767px to 1024px  directly in **lib/web/mage/menu.js** but it's not working. where I have to change to achieve it? I am working on Magento 2.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace style in `web\css\source _navigation.less` in your custom theme.

For `Desktop`

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
```

to (your custom width)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
```

And for `Mobile`

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
```

to (your custom width)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
```

Remember one thing you have to add **max-width is -1 from min-width**.

And after you run command :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

And get more information :-

**[Mobile menu breakpoint in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143519/mobile-menu-breakpoint-in-magento-2)**

Hope this help

Thanks ...